# Scroll to specific horizontal position in DataTables table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am displaying a table using the DataTables library which gets scrolled along the x-axis (it is wider than the display) using

```
scrollX: true
```

Is there any way to display the table already scrolled on initial load (e.g. always have a specific column visible)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? What do you mean by `scrolled on initial load`?

Comment: The DataTable is wider than the display, it displays a horizontal scrollbar, because scrollX is enabled. The initial display when loading the page shows the leftmost entries, the scrollbar sits all the way on the left. Is there a way to adjust the scrollbar to always have a specific column inside the visible viewport (programmatically)?

Comment: I think you should use [Responsive Extension of DataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/).

Comment: How exactly would you propose that the responsive extensions would help to solve my specific problem? I cannot remove columns in between data points since my data won't allow that. I am fine with the table scrolling, I just would like to set an initial position for the scroll bar.